# Convert image to base64 from url

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a image url which I need to convert to base 64

I am trying with the image onload but I do not get it in base64

```
var url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png";

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(e) {
  console.log("herE", e);
};
image.src = url;
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/zubabekeha/edit?js,output)

Comment: have you looked into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try using FileReader Api ??

```js
function base64FromUrl(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            resolve(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    });
}

base64FromUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png")
  .then(function(res) { document.write(res); })
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create `canvas` element
- Draw Image over canvas
- Use [**`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), returns a `data URI` containing a representation of the `image`

```js
var url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png";

var image = new Image();
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
image.onload = function(e) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
};
image.src = url;
```